# Vuejs cli build error

Tags: vue.js, command-line-interface

When im try build my vue app, get this error, im search for 'unexpected space' but don't find it, same as 'async function without a catch block'.
Help me please, i don't know what i must do it now

```
> building for production...Error processing file:
> static/css/app.cba55caf4d9bfa93d0f95f10534f56d6.css (node:8196)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unexpected "space" found.
>     at new error (/home/kawka/Pulpit/programowanie/quiz-app-vuejs/node_modules/postcss-selector-parser/dist/processor.js:29:23)
>     at Parser.error (/home/kawka/Pulpit/programowanie/quiz-app-vuejs/node_modules/postcss-selector-parser/dist/parser.js:234:15)
>     at Parser.pseudo (/home/kawka/Pulpit/programowanie/quiz-app-vuejs/node_modules/postcss-selector-parser/dist/parser.js:362:18)
>     at Parser.parse (/home/kawka/Pulpit/programowanie/quiz-app-vuejs/node_modules/postcss-selector-parser/dist/parser.js:551:22)
>     at Parser.loop (/home/kawka/Pulpit/programowanie/quiz-app-vuejs/node_modules/postcss-selector-parser/dist/parser.js:519:18)
>     at new Parser (/home/kawka/Pulpit/programowanie/quiz-app-vuejs/node_modules/postcss-selector-parser/dist/parser.js:104:21)
>     at Processor.process (/home/kawka/Pulpit/programowanie/quiz-app-vuejs/node_modules/postcss-selector-parser/dist/processor.js:26:21)
>     at getParsed (/home/kawka/Pulpit/programowanie/quiz-app-vuejs/node_modules/postcss-minify-selectors/dist/index.js:32:59)
>     at optimise (/home/kawka/Pulpit/programowanie/quiz-app-vuejs/node_modules/postcss-minify-selectors/dist/index.js:139:21)
>     at /home/kawka/Pulpit/programowanie/quiz-app-vuejs/node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:241:28
>     at /home/kawka/Pulpit/programowanie/quiz-app-vuejs/node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:148:26
>     at Rule.each (/home/kawka/Pulpit/programowanie/quiz-app-vuejs/node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:114:22)
>     at Rule.walk (/home/kawka/Pulpit/programowanie/quiz-app-vuejs/node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:147:21)
>     at /home/kawka/Pulpit/programowanie/quiz-app-vuejs/node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:150:32
>     at Root.each (/home/kawka/Pulpit/programowanie/quiz-app-vuejs/node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:114:22)
>     at Root.walk (/home/kawka/Pulpit/programowanie/quiz-app-vuejs/node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:147:21)
>     at Root.walkRules (/home/kawka/Pulpit/programowanie/quiz-app-vuejs/node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:239:25)
>     at /home/kawka/Pulpit/programowanie/quiz-app-vuejs/node_modules/postcss-minify-selectors/dist/index.js:165:20
>     at LazyResult.run (/home/kawka/Pulpit/programowanie/quiz-app-vuejs/node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:274:20)
>     at LazyResult.asyncTick (/home/kawka/Pulpit/programowanie/quiz-app-vuejs/node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:189:32)
>     at LazyResult.asyncTick (/home/kawka/Pulpit/programowanie/quiz-app-vuejs/node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:201:22)
>     at LazyResult.asyncTick (/home/kawka/Pulpit/programowanie/quiz-app-vuejs/node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:201:22)
> (node:8196) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
> rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
> function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
> not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:8196) [DEP0018]
> DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
> the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
> Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: check css for syntax errors or try removing all comments in css.. find answers to similar issue here https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/250

Comment: Thank your, remove all comments and fix semicolon in css work.